# Pan gesture in UITableViewCell prevents scrolling in UITableView. How to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gesture, pan

I have got an UITableView with a custom TableViewCell. I use a pan gesture for recognizing the positions while moving my finger to the left and to the right. On basis of the finger position I change some values in the labels in this TableViewCell. This works really great. But suddenly I can not scroll the TableView up and down. I already read the reason. Swift can not work with two gesture recognizers at the same time. And I found many examples of people how have nearly the same problem. I tried many of them but I can not fix my problem. I use Swift 5. Could you please describe a bit more precise how to fix my problem? Many thanks

```
import UIKit

class TVCLebensmittel: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        
    }

    @IBAction func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
            // Put my finger on the screen

        } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
            
            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
            // While moving my finger ...

        } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {

            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
            // Lift finger

        }
    }   
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just found a solution which works fine but then I have another problem. The solution: I moved the pan gesture from the TableViewCell to the TableView and it works fine. I can move the table up and down and I can move the finger left and right an I get the position of my finger. But I don't know the underlying table array index. I tried to set a class variable actIndex in willSelectRowAtIndexPath. But when I tap on the screen and move my finger left and right this function will never entered. So this doesn't works.

Comment: How can I figure out on which index I move my finger left and right with my UIPanGestureRecognizer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just share my approach. [link](https://github.com/yilmazedis/InspireMe/blob/master/Gestures/SwipeableCell.swift) It works very well. I needed custom swipe design while perform delete. Try it. If you need more information feel free to ask. Check it if you like.

This gestureRecognizerShouldBegin let you to use scroll while using UIPanGestureRecognizer.

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if (gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UIPanGestureRecognizer.self)) {
        let t = (gestureRecognizer as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).translation(in: contentView)
        let verticalness = abs(t.y)
        if (verticalness > 0) {
            print("ignore vertical motion in the pan ...")
            print("the event engine will >pass on the gesture< to the scroll view")
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! I made a slide button in a tableviewcell and I needed the button to not block the vertical scrolling of the tableview if the user starts scrolling on the button.

Comment: I'm so glad it worked for you. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to insert the pan gesture to the tableview and not to the tableviewcell. So I can listen to the left and right pan and also the up and down movement of the tableview.